# trying to locate file path for where data is stored internally

Tags: android, location, filepath

I have created an app which allows user to create a note and save it.

i know the data is stored in the private storage area of the application but i need to actually view the file in which it is stored on through its file path. can anyone assist on how i can do this please? i have used the FileOutputStream and FileInputStream method

```
public class Utilities {

public static final String FILE_EXTENSION = ".bin";

public static boolean saveNote(Context context, Notes notes){
    String fileName = String.valueOf(notes.getDateTime()) + FILE_EXTENSION;

    FileOutputStream fos;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;

    try {

        fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(notes);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false; //tell the user something went wrong
    }
    return true;
}

public static ArrayList<Notes> getSavedNotes(Context context) {
    ArrayList<Notes> notes = new ArrayList<>();

    File filesDir = context.getFilesDir();
    ArrayList<String> noteFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String file : filesDir.list()) {
        if(file.endsWith(FILE_EXTENSION)) {
            noteFiles.add(file);
        }
    }

    FileInputStream fis;
    ObjectInputStream ois;

    for(int i = 0; i < noteFiles.size(); i++) {
        try{
            fis = context.openFileInput(noteFiles.get(i));
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            notes.add((Notes)ois.readObject());

            fis.close();
            ois.close();



        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }
    }

    return notes;

}

public static Notes getNoteByName(Context context, String fileName) {
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName);
    Notes notes;

    if(file.exists()) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        ObjectInputStream ois;

        try {
            fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            notes = (Notes) ois.readObject();

            fis.close();
            ois.close();

        } catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return notes;
    }

    return null;
}

public static void deleteNote(Context context, String fileName) {
    File Dir = context.getFilesDir();
    File file = new File(Dir, fileName);

    if(file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

File Variables have a method named "getAbsolutePath" that will give you the path of file

For example when you declare a variable as File like this :

```
File filesDir = context.getFilesDir();
```

Then you can use this method to get the file path like this :

```
filesDir.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: sorry not very good with programming, where would i exactly place that method, do i need replace an existing method or just add this line

Comment: thanks for that, i have added the method but i want to be able to view the data that the user stores from file explorer on PC or just find where the data is located and how to get there, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You won't able to see that file physically on to the device because that get stored in internal memory of application. 
Only your application can access that file.

To visualize/explore that file you need rooted device.
Android studio is having capability of file explorer,
Tools Menu > Android > Android Device Monitor
but you will able to see public folder structure.

The answer provided by Mahmood is correct.
To retrive file path you can use below function.

```
File filesDir   = context.getFilesDir();
String filePath = filesDir.getAbsolutePath();
```

All the files will get stored in that location.

Hopefully this answer will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i am new to all of this so just getting used to it at the moment. Also is there a simple way i can encrypt the data being stored?

Comment: Yes, there are so many ways to encrypt and decrypt the content of the file.
- AES-256 algorithm.
- Cryptography principle (public, private keys) to encrypt/decrypt data.
- PGP encryption - (Pretty Good Privacy)

If you are not familiar with Cryptography/PGP algorithm and looking for some simple but strong mechanism then would be good to look for the AES-256 algorithm (On the Internet, you will get so many examples with AES-256).
In AES algorithm you need to keep a master key in a safe place (You can keep it in application memory or on the server).

Comment: Thanks i will look into this further much appreciated